# Why should this equipment question be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

[What type of bass strings produces a very warm and mellow sound?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/what-type-of-bass-strings-produces-a-very-warm-and-mellow-sound)

In my mind, this should be allowed. Why should string types be off topic on a site for musical performance?

I don't see the fundamental difference between the above closed, and this one: [What are the types of strings for an acoustic guitar, and which one is more appropriate for a beginner?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12148/what-are-the-types-of-strings-for-an-acoustic-guitar-and-which-one-is-more-appr)

This is why I would have wanted the equipment closing reason worded differently. "Specific equipment" is too open for interpretation.

Comment: Couple things: First off, [the question was only closed](http://music.stackexchange.com/posts/30827/revisions) not closed, edited re-opened and closed again. Second, the question you linked and the closed are completely different. The linked was asking "What are the differences between the various types of strings?" and the closed question is about "Which strings sound similar this sound clip?". Third regardless of whether or not the question linked is relevant or not, the only case you seem to make is that the linked question is open so this question should be.

Comment: I suggest making an argument for the question and why it should be on topic rather then saying it should be on topic because this question is. I for one stayed out of voting for this because I saw, on-topic, off-topic, and  opinion based elements in the question  and I can see why it was closed and I can also see why it should be reopened, but your post doesn't seem to actually cover any of those reasons.

Comment: @Dom: Regarding previous close, I mixed it up with [this one](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30830/what-are-the-trade-offs-between-using-a-pick-and-fingerstyle-for-guitar), sorry. Will edit my post and remove this comment.

Comment: @Dom: You are correct, there are several elements in this question. I would like us to focus on the acceptable elements in a post, and if they are good enough, let the question be. Edit to make it better is good (which I did), but closing this one I think is wrong.

Comment: @Dom: My reason is that questions about string types should be on topic for this site, simple and plain. Stated in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adding an answer mostly to be able to mark this issue as answered.)

The question is no longer on hold, so the current answer seems to be that it should not be closed. I don't think the discussion will go further at this point in time. In borderline cases, please consider if the question really needs to be closed, of if there are small edits that can be made to push it over the edge of usefulness.

Answer (score -3):

I waited until there were already 4 votes specifically so I would not have mod close powers - my vote was purely a community one - and my view is that this question is entirely unanswerable, unlike the acoustic guitar strings one you linked.

We have already had discussion on what warm and mellow mean, and while there was a fair bit of agreement, there was enough variety to make it obvious warm and mellow were not empirical terms, and they depend on opinion.

If you look at the two answers that question has - the accepted answer says one thing, and the highest voted answer has a completely different opinion. Which brings it back to my reason for voting to close: it's entirely opinion based.

String types == not off topic, per se

Comment: Regarding number of votes: There are just four names showing, but I don't know what is displayed. When it comes to bass I would think these terms are enough defined. The answer contained a sound sample (admittedly it could have been shorter and preferably not a song), further showing what was meant

Comment: But questions about what string types produce which sound is are topic, if concepts as mellow, harsh, bright, full etc. are off the table. What string is good for a beginner does sound like a pretty opinion based question to me, as far as the linked, liked question goes.

Comment: Some specific equipment is indeed mentioned in the post, per se. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the discussion about what warm and mellow mean, and obviously there is room for personal interpretation, but there is a measurable quality involved. As far as I'm concerned, the question has been answered, maybe it wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but I got some useful and informative replies and comments. No one was pushing equipment, arguing about personal tastes etc., and clearly that's was the rule is about. This is silly.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername You're right about the sample, but it was obviously too late to record a good one after a string broke, and, although I probably could dig up something more suitable, I just posted a recording of a sparse arrangement where the bass is clearly heard. Thanks for your support!

Comment: While “mellow” may not have a *unanimously* agreed-upon meaning, it’s pretty conventional vocabulary for the kind of sound that flatwound and coated strings make. It’s easy enough to check whether that’s the sound the poster is talking about.

Comment: I'm a bit on the fence here. Not sure the the subjectivity of what mellow is makes the question outright bad, it's definitely not an opinion poll. A crapload of musical terms are inherently subjective.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I can understand that. And it seems several people were on the same fence. I would like us to change so we don't fall on the close side of the fence in these matters.

Comment: @Meaningful Agreed, that's why I [voted to leave it open](http://music.stackexchange.com/review/close/16188). I think maybe if the last sentence was altered so it didn't read like a recommend-me-a-brand question it might be more generally accepted. Not sure if the answer which does that should be edited too...it seems like good knowledge specific to the problem but does sort of come across and a product recommendation.

Comment: Since the asker of the question accepted an answer, doesn't that call in to question your view that the question is "entirely unanswerable"?

Comment: Not really, no. Answerable, in SE terms, tends to mean 'has a single correct answer' - look at the highest voted answer: it states something entirely different to the accepted answer. One says roundwound, one says flatwound: it is personal opinion.

Comment: @DrMayhem: I think we need to be less stringent than that on this site. I think we already are. Both ways might be good ways, and something was learned in relation to the question.

Comment: Totally agree. The conversation around it has helped clarify community position a bit. Wouldn't change my personal vote but I'm not going to mod vote it